# Is there a non-preemptive version of Poisoning the Well fallacy?

Tags: fallacies

Poisoning the well seems to rely on ad hominem happening prior to hearing the source's arguments. But what happens if the ad hominen/discrediting happens after hearing their arguments? What would such a fallacy be called? It seems like it might be some kind of argument from authority fallacy? Or am I overthinking this and it's simply ad hom?

https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Poisoning-the-Well

Example:

Person 1. Your claim is misleading/false according to Snopes

Person 2. Snopes is not trustworthy because they plagiarized 60 articles

Comment: It's just ad hominem.

Comment: I think it behoves the OP to suggest that time might be if it’s not simply ad hominem.

Comment: Like what they call [mudslinging](https://politicaldictionary.com/words/mudslinging/) in politics? Some list it under fallacies now too, e.g. [ThoughtCo](https://www.thoughtco.com/ad-hominem-fallacy-1689062). Part of the trend of calling every rhetorical tactic a "fallacy".

Comment: I added an example to my question

Comment: Well, questioning the reliability of a news source is not necessarily a fallacy, because we're depending on the news source to be authoritative and accurate.  Although in this case the argument is weak - what does plagiarism have to do with factual accuracy?